# Elisp: Macro expansion at load time with eval of undefined variable

Tags: emacs, lisp-macros

Lisp-rookie here.

My goal is to define a macro that will make the keys of a dotted alist available as variables to access the corresponding values, hence the name »let-dotted-alist«. So what I want is:

```
(setq foo '((a . "aa") (b . "bb")))

(let-dotted-alist foo
(message (concat a b)))
                           ==> "aabb"
```

Here's the best I could come up with so far:

```
(defmacro let-dotted-alist (alist &rest body)
"binds the car of each element of dotted ALIST to the corresponding cdr and makes them available  as variables in BODY."
  `(let ,(nreverse 
      (mapcar    
       (lambda (p) (list (car p) (cdr p))) 
       (eval alist)))
     ,@body))
```

The problem here is the `eval`. I need it in order to be able to pass the alist as a variable (`foo`) rather than a literal, which is the main use case when defining functions. For the macro to work out the code this variable needs to be bound already. Still everywhere I read that the use of eval tends to indicate a flaw in the code? Is there a way around it?

This would be a somewhat academic problem if Emacs 24 hadn't introduced eager macro expansion which wants to expand the macro at load time, when the variable (`dotlist` in the following example) that should provide the alist  is still void:

```
(defun concat-my-cdrs (dotlist)
  (let-dotted-alist dotlist
            (print (concat a b))))
```

Depending on how I evaluate this I either get »mapcar: Symbol's value as variable is void: dotlist« or »Eager macro-expansion failure: (void-variable dotlist)«. This makes sense of course, because the variable dotlist is indeed void at load time.

Now before I try to find a workaround along the lines of (locally) disabling eager macro expansion, is there any way to improve on the macro definition to avoid the `eval` altogether?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something trivial... but why wouldn't you just use `,alist` instead of `(eval alist)`? (In fact, you are under `,` already, so what's exactly missing?)

Comment: Sorry, disregard my previous comment. Got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can avoid `eval`, the way the problem is stated: macroexpand `let`-bindings depending on a variable. The only way not to use `eval` would be to postpone the variable evaluation until after macroexpand, but it contradicts the requirement of expanding the `let` bindings. I think I am stating something that is obvious to you.

So the question apparently is whether your requirements can be changed to eliminate the need for `eval`. Which would mean either avoiding `let`-bindings, or making the bindings explicit in macro parameters. It's up to you to decide if it's acceptable, but my personal take is - `eval` is not so bad as to kill your use case. I would keep `eval` there. (I did essentially the same recently in Clojure where I needed to bind same local symbols to different values, emulating OCaml functors. That's a digression to explain why I am probably biased towards keeping the way you did it.)

I might not be aware of some elisp-specific tricks - although even then I'd probably prefer `eval` to some trickery I've never come across of so far.

Comment: Thanks for wrapping your head around this! I'll mark this one solved. It's somewhat comforting to know, that there's at least no obvious thing that I've missed. In case I find a good workaround for the eager expansion problem I'm going to post it here.

Comment: Thanks, would be interesting to see how you handle it.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll mention that eager-macroexpansion does not introduce a new problem: the same issue shows up in earlier Emacsen if you try to byte-compile your file.

As for avoiding `eval`, you kind of can, by using something else which uses `eval`, e.g. `cl-progv`:

```
(defmacro let-dotted-alist (alist &rest body)
  (macroexp-let2 nil alist alist
    `(cl-progv (mapcar #'car ,alist)
               (mapcar #'cdr ,alist)
       ,@body)))
```

But note that the semantics is a bit different: the variables can be only dynamically scoped rather than lexically scoped, because the list of variables will be known only at run-time.